# Convert Week Diff to Start of Week Date SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I convert all week diff column values to the start date of each week?

Sample data:

```
Week Diff | Value
1         | 20000
2         | 30000
3         | 40000
```

Expected results:

```
Week Diff | Value
6/24/2018 | 20000
6/17/2018 | 30000
6/10/2018 | 40000
```

I've seen similar posts but I don't understand how to change solution for my needs. For example

```
declare @wk int  = week_diff
select dateadd(week,@wk-1, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,-1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)), 0))
```

Please advise.

Comment: please provide sample data and expected result

Comment: You have to explain what `Week Diff` is? Diff from what exactly, today or...?

Comment: Week Diff from today, thank you.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: So you need the first date of the week that is the current one -[Week Diff]+1??

Comment: In theory yes. If week diff = 0, then the output should be the first date of the current week (7/1/2018). If week diff = 1, then the output should be 6/24/2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    convert(date,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,getdate())-[Week Diff], 0))
from yourtable
```